# Pip install fail on Mac "Getting requirements to build wheel ... error"

Tags: python, macos, installation, pip, scipy

When I try to use pip to install packages on Mac I run into this error:

"Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully."

It only happens when I try to install certain packages (scipy and sklearn). Other packages install fine (numpy and pandas).

I am on a Mac running Python: 3.10.7 and pip 22.2.2. I am relatively new to all of this so please let me know if you need more information and I appreciate any help.

FULL ERROR:

cobykirkland@Cobys-MacBook-Pro ~ % pip install scipy
Collecting scipy
Using cached scipy-1.9.1.tar.gz (42.0 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [61 lines of output]
The Meson build system
Version: 0.62.2
Source dir: /private/var/folders/nh/bw_22w4j4pg23hczs34hg5jc0000gn/T/pip-install-keuagdr1/scipy_af79793bfc2c43319072f465a4dd6b51
Build dir: /private/var/folders/nh/bw_22w4j4pg23hczs34hg5jc0000gn/T/pip-install-keuagdr1/scipy_af79793bfc2c43319072f465a4dd6b51/.mesonpy-j1n79wk8/build
Build type: native build
Project name: SciPy
Project version: 1.9.1
C compiler for the host machine: cc (clang 12.0.5 "Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)")
C linker for the host machine: cc ld64 650.9
C++ compiler for the host machine: c++ (clang 12.0.5 "Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)")
C++ linker for the host machine: c++ ld64 650.9
Host machine cpu family: aarch64
Host machine cpu: arm64
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-but-set-variable: NO
Library m found: YES

```
  ../../meson.build:41:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['gfortran'], ['flang'], ['nvfortran'], ['pgfortran'], ['ifort'], ['g95']]
  The following exception(s) were encountered:
  Running "gfortran --version" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gfortran'"
  Running "gfortran -V" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gfortran'"
  Running "flang --version" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'flang'"
  Running "flang -V" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'flang'"
  Running "nvfortran --version" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nvfortran'"
  Running "nvfortran -V" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nvfortran'"
  Running "pgfortran --version" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pgfortran'"
  Running "pgfortran -V" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pgfortran'"
  Running "ifort --version" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifort'"
  Running "ifort -V" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifort'"
  Running "g95 --version" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'g95'"
  Running "g95 -V" gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'g95'"
  
  A full log can be found at /private/var/folders/nh/bw_22w4j4pg23hczs34hg5jc0000gn/T/pip-install-keuagdr1/scipy_af79793bfc2c43319072f465a4dd6b51/.mesonpy-j1n79wk8/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
  + meson setup --native-file=/private/var/folders/nh/bw_22w4j4pg23hczs34hg5jc0000gn/T/pip-install-keuagdr1/scipy_af79793bfc2c43319072f465a4dd6b51/.mesonpy-native-file.ini -Ddebug=false -Doptimization=2 --prefix=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10 /private/var/folders/nh/bw_22w4j4pg23hczs34hg5jc0000gn/T/pip-install-keuagdr1/scipy_af79793bfc2c43319072f465a4dd6b51 /private/var/folders/nh/bw_22w4j4pg23hczs34hg5jc0000gn/T/pip-install-keuagdr1/scipy_af79793bfc2c43319072f465a4dd6b51/.mesonpy-j1n79wk8/build
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
      main()
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 130, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "/private/var/folders/nh/bw_22w4j4pg23hczs34hg5jc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-zc95ob3s/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 969, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      with _project(config_settings) as project:
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
      return next(self.gen)
    File "/private/var/folders/nh/bw_22w4j4pg23hczs34hg5jc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-zc95ob3s/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 948, in _project
      with Project.with_temp_working_dir(
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
      return next(self.gen)
    File "/private/var/folders/nh/bw_22w4j4pg23hczs34hg5jc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-zc95ob3s/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 777, in with_temp_working_dir
      yield cls(source_dir, tmpdir, build_dir)
    File "/private/var/folders/nh/bw_22w4j4pg23hczs34hg5jc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-zc95ob3s/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 682, in __init__
      self._configure(reconfigure=bool(build_dir) and not native_file_mismatch)
    File "/private/var/folders/nh/bw_22w4j4pg23hczs34hg5jc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-zc95ob3s/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 713, in _configure
      self._meson(
    File "/private/var/folders/nh/bw_22w4j4pg23hczs34hg5jc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-zc95ob3s/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 696, in _meson
      return self._proc('meson', *args)
    File "/private/var/folders/nh/bw_22w4j4pg23hczs34hg5jc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-zc95ob3s/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 691, in _proc
      subprocess.check_call(list(args))
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 369, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['meson', 'setup', '--native-file=/private/var/folders/nh/bw_22w4j4pg23hczs34hg5jc0000gn/T/pip-install-keuagdr1/scipy_af79793bfc2c43319072f465a4dd6b51/.mesonpy-native-file.ini', '-Ddebug=false', '-Doptimization=2', '--prefix=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10', '/private/var/folders/nh/bw_22w4j4pg23hczs34hg5jc0000gn/T/pip-install-keuagdr1/scipy_af79793bfc2c43319072f465a4dd6b51', '/private/var/folders/nh/bw_22w4j4pg23hczs34hg5jc0000gn/T/pip-install-keuagdr1/scipy_af79793bfc2c43319072f465a4dd6b51/.mesonpy-j1n79wk8/build']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

Comment: Try this one py -m ensurepip --default-pip and then py -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel and finally type py -m pip install scipy. If py does not work try python or python3

Comment: and I'm sharing two links for you to review ::  https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/16116 and https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/13409

Answer (score 0):

scipy provides pip-installable wheels for `scipy-1.9.2-cp310-cp310-macosx_12_0_arm64.whl`. For various reasons arm64 wheels are only available for Monterey, not Big Sur. I'm guessing that your OS is currently Big Sur, otherwise the correct wheel should've been installed. You have a few options:

1. Upgrade to Monterey.
2. Use conda to install scipy
3. Try using rosetta to run an x86_64 Python, there are wheels for that architecture that will run on Monterey - this will be more complicated.